# Can one fly to Iran with an expired passport and a Canadian permanent resident document?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, passports, paperwork, iranian-citizens

My mom's passport will be expired on 28 however she has ticket to back to Iran on 27 from Toronto via Frankfurt. She has permanent residence card but she is not Canadian citizen, therefore the only passport she has is the Iranian one. When she changes the flight in Frankfurt, her passport will be expired. Can she travel in this situation?

Comment: Not an exact dupe bcs here the OP does not have a valid passport at the transit in FRA. Voting to leave open.

Comment: ... Not an exact dupe because passport won't actually be expired.

Answer (score 3):

If the trip is one booking (meaning, she doesn't need to clear immigration to pick up luggage) the passport requirements for entering Germany do **not** apply to her (she also needs no visa as she has a Canadian PR card), and only the entry requirements for Iran are relevant.

And as stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ir&DE=ir&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=ca&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Nationals of Iran are allowed to enter with an expired
>     passport.

So yes, she can travel without problems

Comment: Do you have a source for the part about no need for a valid passport while in transit? Not doubting you but I could not find any myself.

Comment: @mts Timatic doesn't say anything explicit, simply because most of the time you won't be dealing with national authorities when merely connecting in a country

Comment: True you won't encounter any national authorities in most cases, but I have no idea whether airline personal would still mind upon boarding/check-in for the initial flight?